# Tips on aligning text with accents

Tags: typography, alignment, critique

I'm trying to align the following words (see attached screen capture). But the accent on the *á* is making it tricky. There’s always a space somewhere that doesn’t look quite right, etc.

Any good-practice tips on handling such a situation?

[image]

(The typeface is Candara Bold.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Outline the type and shrink the accent/change its shape to be shorter so that it doesn't stick up past the capital T.
2. Make "Tanowul" all caps, then place the word "the" over the T and the word "expanded" over "nowul" so that the accent hangs out in the space between the two words.
3. Make "Tanowul" all caps, then place the words "the expanded" directly over the "nowul" portion and allow the entire design to be right aligned. If you did this I would enlarge "guide book" to fit the entire space under "tanowul" (or if you don't want to enlarge the type, you can increase the tracking).

Comment: Very good suggestions. Thank you. Number 3 has my preference at this point. I actually had "tanowul" in all-caps in a previous version, and the other words in small-caps. It was indeed easier to align then. But I switched because of the tone of the words really: "tanowul" is more fluid, bizarre, dreamlike, whereas "guidebook" and "expanded" have a more regimented, ordered, quasi-technical tone to them. Hence having "tanowul" in small caps, etc.